# scrapy python take args

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to implement args into the spider for the url. For example:

```
scrapy crawl test -a url="https://example.com"
```

And after that i want to automatically take the start_urls and convert it automatically to domain_allowed. Ex:

```
domain_allowed = ['example.com']
```

And after that i want to pass just the word **Example** to the mysql pipeline where it creates the table using Just the word **Example** from the **domain_allowed**

This is what i have for now:

```
class Spider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'seeker'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        urls = kwargs.pop('urls', [])
        if urls:
            self.start_urls = urls.split(',')
        self.logger.info(self.start_urls)

        # take the arg "urls" and convert it to allowed_domains
        url = "".join(urls)
        self.allowed_domains = [url.split('/')[-1]]

        super(SeekerSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


   # i have to use "domain" here and not inside the function parge_page or __init__
   domain = domain_allowed.replace(".", "_")  
   # create folder with the domain name

   def parse_page(self, response):
       ...
```

Basically i need to use the **self.allowed_domains** outside the function...Thats my problem...the variable **domain** doesn't take it.

And this is part of my pipelines.py

```
class MySQLPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.connect = pymysql.connect(...)
        self.cursor = self.connect.cursor()
        # print "Input the name of the table: "  <-- its commented
        # tablename = raw_input(" ")   <-- its commented
        date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y_%m_%d_%H_%M")
        self.tablename = kwargs.pop('tbl', '')
        self.newname = self.tablename + "_" + date
        print self.newname
        # create a different way to create a tablename
        # importing the "allowed_domain" and strip it 
        # and give tablename
```

The pipelines i ve done it this way..but its not good...i want to take the **allowed_domain** from the spider and pass it here and split it to take only the name of the domain without the *.com* or *.whatever*

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

On my phone so sorry about formatting...

I would use the spider object in the process item function:
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    spider.allowed_domains.replace(".","_")

Comment: yes but it will go throught it every request...so basically it will created it 100 times.... i need to do it outside...what if i do **def __init__ (self, spider)** instead...actually i already tried and it doesn't work...i can't do spider.allowed_domain ...it doesn't exists